# Take 4 places after decimal for a double variable

Tags: c#

I dont want to round I want to take 4 places after decimal.

Example:

```
double something = 0.00038;
```

I want the result to be

```
0.0003   // 8 is discarded
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you using this for a display, or do you need to number for mathematical calculations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double result = Math.Truncate(10000 * something) / 10000;
```

Comment: @MikePrecup's comment on the answer using `float` applies here as well...  better to use Decimal

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply, truncate, then divide.

```
decimal f = 100.0123456;
f = Math.Truncate(f * 10000) / 10000;
```

Here is a nice little function you can use

```
public static decimal MyTruncate(decimal input, int digit) {
    return Math.Truncate(input * Math.Pow(10, -digit)) / Math.Pow(10, -digit);
}
```

this function truncates anything to the right of the specified `digit`

where 0 is the ones place, 1 is the tens place and -1 is the tenths place

Comment: Using `float` could lead to results like 0.000299999999999

Comment: @MikePrecup which data type do you suggest?

Comment: `Decimal` would prevent that.

Comment: `MyTruncate` never uses `input`.

Comment: @MikePrecup lol would you look at that...thanks, EDIT MADE